# What wrong with my loop .Need to calculate a running total

Tags: c#

I have to build some logic to write some sort of scoreboard. The idea is this:

There are many stages:

- 1st stage you have 2 numbers. 7 and 3=10
- 2nd stage you  have another 2 numbers. 5 and 1 =6

After the loop has finished, the wanted result should be:

- Stage 1 total score=15  (total 1st Stage + firstTry of secondStage)
- Stage 2 total score=21 (total 1st Stage + (firstTry + SecondTry of SecondStage)

What's wrong with my loop? I dont seem to get the wanted resoult.

```
private void Calculate(Player player)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < player.Game.Stages.Length; i++)
    {
        int firstThrow = player.Game.Stages[i].FirstTry;
  int secondThrow = player.Game.Stages[i].SecondTry;
  int sumFirstAndSecond = firstThrow + secondThrow;
  //If firstTry + SecondTry==10 is spare
  if ((sumFirstAndSecond == 10) && (firstThrow != 10) && i != player.Game.Stages.Length- 1)
  {
      int stageScore= player.Game.Stages[i].TotalScore + 
                         player.Game.Stages[i + 1].FirstTry;
             player.Game.Stages[i].TotalScore = stageScore;
         }
    }
}

public class Stage
{
    public int FirstTry { get; set; }
    public int SecondTry { get; set; }
    public int TotalScore { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Game = new Game(name);
    }

    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public Game(string playerName)
    {
        PlayerName = playerName;
        Stages = new Stage[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages.Length; i++)
        {
       Stages[i] = new Stage();
        }
    }

    public Stage[] Stages { get; internal set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: sorry, but _total 1st Stage + (firstTry + SecondTry of SecondStage)_ shouldn't be 16?

Comment: @Marco 15 is correct.is the firstStage,Total + SecondStage.FirstTry

Comment: I'm talkin about second stage result: are you sure it shouldn't be 16? Why 21? You're counting 2nd stage's FirstTry twice...

Comment: @Akram I get 6 for second stage when I should be getting 21

Comment: @Marco: That's what (American) bowling does... and only if the previous frame took two tries to get 10.  If any frame gets 10 on the first try, the next two tries get added in (and double-counted).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling#Scoring

Comment: @Ben=yes correct. what Am I doing wrong

Comment: @user: Looks like you've just forgotten to include the previous total, i.e. `Stages[i-1].TotalScore`

Comment: Algorithms can be frustrating but in general, staring at the code when it's not working doesn't help.  The debugger is your friend.  Console.WriteLine is your friend.  Use those tools first before giving up.

Comment: @Ben where should that go I mean previous total.I think that is it.You code looks truncated.what is the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
private void Calculate(Player player)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < player.Game.Stages.Length; i++)
    {
        int firstThrow = player.Game.Stages[i].FirstTry;
        int secondThrow = player.Game.Stages[i].SecondTry;
        int sumFirstAndSecond = firstThrow + secondThrow;
        if ((sumFirstAndSecond == 10) && (firstThrow != 10) && i != player.Game.Stages.Length- 1)
        {
            int stageScore= player.Game.Stages[i].TotalScore + player.Game.Stages[i + 1].FirstTry;
            player.Game.Stages[i].TotalScore = sumFirstAndSecond + stageScore;
         }
         else if (i > 0) player.Game.Stages[i].TotalScore = player.Game.Stages[i - 1].TotalScore + sumFirstAndSecond;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I am getting 15 and 6 instead of 15 and 21.Also the problem is that the second time round it loops it does not seem to add it up

Comment: @user231465: What is frameLength?

Answer (score 0):

Bowling?
Try this, and do not forget to add misses (as 0).
Should work for both running and final scoring.

```
// All balls, including misses (0)!
public readonly IList<int> _balls = new List<int>();
private int _currentBall;

public int CalculateTotalScore()
{
   int score = 0;
   _currentBall = 0;

   for (var frame = 0; frame < 10; frame++)
   {
       if (_currentBall >= _balls.Count)
           break;

       if (_balls[_currentBall] == 10)
       {
           // Strrrike!
           score += AggregateScoreFromCurrentBall(3);
           _currentBall++;
       }
       else if (AggregateScoreFromCurrentBall(2) == 10)
       {
           // Spare
           score += AggregateScoreFromCurrentBall(3);
           _currentBall += 2;
       }
       else
       {
           score += AggregateScoreFromCurrentBall(2);
           _currentBall += 2;
       }
   }

   return score;
}

private int AggregateScoreFromCurrentBall(int numberOfBallsToSum)
{
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBallsToSum; i++)
        if (_currentBall + i < _balls.Count)
           sum += _balls[_currentBall + i];

    return sum;
}
```